# Three sets of cards , A , B , C , each consisting of eight cards. Redistribute the cards .

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I have three sets of cards -- A , B , C , each consisting of eight cards. I  decide to redistribute the cards to form the three sets of eight cards each. How many ways can it be done if no card  has all the same teammates as before  ? (All $24$ cards are distinct. )

We are allowed to use only inclusion-exclusion.

Can anyone give me any hint?

**My attempt :** Universal set will be $24!$ . But I can not find the excluded sets. If only $A$ remains intact , but $B$   and $C$ do not. We will get $16! - (8!)^3$ sets.  Same will go when $B , C $ remain intact.  $A$ , $B$ , $C$ remain intact in $(8!)^3$ ways.

So the required number will be $24! - 3 \times (16! - (8!)^3) - (8!)^3$ .

Comment: What have you tried? How do you intend to use PIE? E.g. If you were limited to just $A$ and $B$, how many ways are there to redistribute them?

Comment: In that case it would be $24! - (12!)^2$ . Am I right?@CalvinLin

Comment: There aren't $24!$ ways to split the cards up into $3$ groups of $8$.

Comment: I do not see why. Remember that the order in which you arrange the first 8 (or 12) cards into set A doesn't matter, so ... ... (In particular, I disagree that "Universal set will be 24!")

Comment: Can you tell me what will be the number of elements in $U$ ? Is it $^{24}C_8 \times ^{16}C_8 $ ?

Comment: Can you tell me what will be the number of elements in $U$ ? Is it $^{24}C_8 \times ^{16}C_8 $ ? @saulspatz

Answer (score 3):

We can arrange the cards into $3$ groups of $8$ dealing the first $8$ cards into one pile, the next *4* into a second pile, and the remaining $8$ into a third pile.  There are $24!$ ways the deck can be arranged originally, and it doesn't matter what order the cards are dealt into a particular pile, so that gives $\frac{24!}{(8!)^3}$.  Furthermore, the order of the piles themselves doesn't matter, so there are  $$\frac{24!}{(8!)^33!}$$ ways to divide the cards into $3$ groups of $8$.

I divided by $3!$ because there are $3!$ ways to arrange the piles themselves; we don't really care if a group of $8$ cards is in the first pile or the third pile, so long as they're in the same pile.

Now we need to exclude those arrangements that include one of the forbidden piles.  There are $3$ such piles.  When we choose one, we have to split the remaining $16$ cards into $2$ groups of $8$.  Reasoning as above there are $$\frac{16!}{(8!)^22!}$$ ways to do that, which gives $$\frac{24!}{(8!)^33!}-3\frac{16!}{(8!)^22!}$$ ways so far.

Now we still have to worry about double-counting.  Suppose two of the forbidden groups are included. Then so is the third.  This arrangement has been subtracted $3$ time so we have to add it back in twice, giving a final answer of  $$\frac{24!}{(8!)^33!}-3\frac{16!}{(8!)^22!}+2$$

Comment: Can you please once check my attempt ? @saulspatz

Comment: @sani It's not correct.  You're staring out with the wrong number of possibilities, as indicated in my answer.

Comment: No I think I need little more explanation. Besides , I can not understand why you divided by $3!$ . @saulspatz

Comment: You may not have seen the name of the piles. There are three sets of cards. @saulspatz

Comment: @sani Why do the names of the piles matter?  How can it matter if I call them first, second, and third, instead of A, B, and C?

Comment: I do not think it should be divided by $3!$. I can not understand it. @saulspatz

Comment: @sani How many ways are there to arrange the cards so that all the cards are in the same group as before?  If you think the answer is $6$, then you can modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: "we don't really care if a group of $8$ cards is in the first pile or the third pile, so long as they're in the same pile." No this does matter here, Please read the question.@saulspatz

Comment: @sani Oddly enough, I did read the question before taking the trouble to write an answer.  I'm trying to help you.  please try to show a little bit of civility.

Comment: Okay.. I am not commenting anymore. Thank you for trying to help me.@saulspatz

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Corrected, thanks.